# jQueryUI tabs() not working if the page containing it was loaded by AJAX (PJAX actually)

Tags: dom, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, pjax

My question is about how jQuery finds various DOM nodes that don't exist until they are loaded by AJAX.

My particular issue is that my jQueryUI tabs() script only works if it is included together with the tabs div on the page fragment loaded by AJAX. This script doesn't work if was loaded as part of the original main template page before the tabs div exists (i.e., before being ajax loaded).

To explain what I mean here's some simple code description:

```
 $('a.ajax').live('click', function(){
   $.ajax({ url: '/get_page_with_tabs', 
         success: function(data){ 
         $('div#ajax').append(data); // the content that gets replaced
         } 
   });
});

 $('div#tabs').tabs(); 
 // this script must be part of the "data" along with the <div id="tabs></div>
 // it can't be loaded along with the main template page which contains: <div id="ajax">    </div> and the $.ajax script
```

Just one side-note is that I'm actually using [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) but this appears functionally identical to jQuery AJAX regarding the asynchronous div loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how jQuery finds various DOM nodes that don't exist until they are loaded by AJAX`

It doesn't find.

Move the tabs initialization code to the AJAX response handler:

```
$('a.ajax').live('click', function(){
   $.ajax({ url: '/get_page_with_tabs', 
         success: function(data){ 
         $('div#ajax').append(data); // the content that gets replaced
         $('div#tabs').tabs(); 
         } 
   });
});
```

Using `live` and `on` you can attach event handlers to elements which do not exist in the page yet (and may be added later by an ajax call or `append` sort of function).

jQuery can catch these events because of the [event "bubbling"](http://www.aghausman.net/javascript/event-bubbling-in-javascript.html) - basically, a higher/upper parent catches the child event...

Comment: hi J.Bruni, see the code I wrote because I am using the live() method, though I guess my <a> elements are parents to the tabs div so the bubbling goes in the wrong direction and wouldn't work, yes/no?

Comment: Because jQuery can't find nodes that does not exist. They need to exist before you can attach something to them. You may have the sensation it is not like that because of `live`-like features. I added a few words in my answer, but if you read the jQuery documentation about `on`, you will fully understand: http://api.jquery.com/on/ - the "Direct and delegated events" section is the core, but I recommend reading the entire document with attention.

Comment: "parents" is related to the **nesting** of the elements, not the order of creation: `<ul><li>Hi</li></ul>` - here, `li` is child of `ul`, and `ul` is parent of `li`

Comment: hi J.Bruni, sorry I think I previously misspoke: if my <a> elements are parents or definitely not children of the div tabs then shouldn't the tabs() clicking bubble up or at the least do nothing to parents and therefore work regardless of the ajax, yes/no?

Comment: It does not matter the direction of the bubbling. When `$('div#tabs').tabs();` code runs, it will apply only to the `div#tabs` that exists at that moment in the page (not in the future).

Comment: What `$('a.ajax').live('click', function` does? It attachs the "function" as the "click event handler" for all `a.ajax` anchors which exist now **and in the future** (new `a.ajax` elements included later) - and this is only possible because of the "event bubbling" - nothing to do with the tabs or div#tabs

Comment: ok I think I got it: Bubbling is irrelevant in this scenario. You need to initialize tabs() when its div exists.

Comment: ok bubbling and tabs initializing, separate concepts, think i'm getting it

Comment: Yes. Maybe I have mixed subjects in a confusing way. In this scenario, you need to initialize tabs() when its div exist. I only wanted to go further in the **why** it **seems** you can do some stuff with elements which are not present yet... (not the tabs case)

Comment: one last question, do you know if you could make a plugin that might initialize functions in the event that their selectors get created dynamically (i.e., by ajax)? I'm not sure if this is just the way javascript is designed or you could programmatically do something about this tabs() initializing issue, thanks again!

Comment: You shouldn't need it, but it is an interesting idea. Something like `$('div#tabs').later(function(){ $(this).tabs() });`... it is doable, but for all cases of DOM insertion it would be difficult; restricting scope for a few cases (like AJAX call returning HTML...) it would be much easier.

Comment: hmm, yeah I think the ajax case would make it worth it since so many people use that. so the later() function you mention doesn't exist, that's only a hypothetical jQuery plugin as of now? As you can probably tell, I'm not at the point where I'd know how to do something like this but it is definitely an interesting idea for the future. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you ajax load the tabs, you need to initialize them once ajax is complete. If you try intializing withn the `ready` event , on page load ,the tab html doesn't exist.

If you replace all the tab html, same story

Comment: thanks charlietfl, so by "intialize" you mean calling the tabs() function? If this is the case I guess I can't change from what I said was working for me.

Comment: correct, call tabs() function within the success- after you insert the html.